# Facebook - Can't submit new Open Graph type, submit grayed out. How to submit?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I added a few Open Graph types to an app on facebook, following all the instructions. I clicked save changes and when you go to review status the Submit button next to the types is grayed out. I can't submit them, and thus they can't be used - and they can't be used until submitted and reviewed which I can't do.

The error shown when hovering the button is: You, or this app's Open Graph Test User, must have published this action before being able to submit for review.

What should I do to fix this? How do I unpublish the action to submit it (i assume that's what I need to do) and then republish it after it's reviewed?

I tried finding instructions for unpublishing an action to no avail.

EDIT: Tested with a completely new app I created, just random test name stuff. Same thing happens. I literally added an action type within seconds of creating the app, and tried to submit in review status and still the submit button is grayed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't published those stories yet. You can publish each story using the graph API explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). Part of the submission process is including a screenshot of the story published on your wall, so you need to publish one before you can submit.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that. The formulation of the sentence explaining that someone must have published the story before submitting is absurd in that case. It implies someone doing something wrong and not something that needs to be done.

Comment: That does resolve the issue. Facebook should have made this clearer and should have used a proper tense to describe the issues with their grayed out buttons. Thank you very much.